# Run Executable (with Support Files) In a Separate Directory

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to run "AutoRun.exe" from an iso file mounted to DriveLetter:\

```
& "${DriveLetter}:\AutoRun.exe"
```

Using the above method I can properly tell PowerShell to run the executable, but it expects the support files (AutoRun.cfg, etc) to be in the place of execution (in this case my Desktop). I want this to be able to work no matter the location of the PowerShell script.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the working directory to whereever the required files are located. If they reside in `${DriveLetter}:\` change to that directory:

```
Set-Location "${DriveLetter}:\"
& "${DriveLetter}:\AutoRun.exe"
```

If they reside in the same folder as the PowerShell script change to that directory:

```
Set-Location (Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
& "${DriveLetter}:\AutoRun.exe"
```

or (PowerShell v3 and newer):

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
& "${DriveLetter}:\AutoRun.exe"
```